# Swift: If Let Conundrum

Tags: ios, swift, if-statement, nsurl

Now I know there are other questions that have already been answered about the *Initializer for conditional binding must have optional type* error, but I have tried those solutions and none seem to work or be about NSURL. Mine is specifically talking about it can't be NSURL. I have no idea what to do to fix it.

```
let attemptedUrl = NSURL(string: "http://www.weather-forecast.com/locations/" +
textField.text!.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "-") + 
"/forecasts/latest")!

if let url = attemptedUrl {
```

The specific line of code that is having an error is the
    *if let url = attemptedUrl {*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are force unwrapping the result of your call to NSURL(string:), this is what the ! does at the end of that statement.  As such, your attemptedUrl variable is not an optional type, so unwrapping it again with an if let statement (in addition to your force unwrap with the ! statement) is redundant and will not compile.

I would recommend reading the [Optionals](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID323) section of [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language) for more information.